# Collision detection in 3d

Tags: collision-detection, algorithm

what is the simplest algorithm for collision detection that respects the following requirements:

- The collision is only between cubes that are always aligned with the axis of the world (not rotated).
- Collision between frames must be detected. I mean, since the objects of the game may be moving very fast, I can have two objects that in the next frame are not colliding, but that have collided between the current and the next frame.
- The movement of the objects is accelerated (we have gravity).
- I need to know where did the objects collide (a point coordinate, the time between frames when this collision happened, ...)

Thanks.

Comment: I don't know what algorithm, but why you don't use existing physic engines (such as Nvidia physX)?

Comment: Because it's for a university project, where we only can use opengl and freeglut. And none of them provide support for collision detection.

Comment: How about `Bullet`. [Bullet is a free and open-source physics engine which simulates collision detection, soft and rigid body dynamics.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bullet_%28software%29)

Comment: We cannot use any engine, the collision detection must be implemented by us. I'm looking for something like AABB.

Comment: I don't know about 3D, but I answer your question [Here](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/86109/collision-detection-between-2-irregular-shapes/86113#86113) which may give you some idea :)

Comment: Some random thoughts: it is trivial to check if two spheres collide. If spheres that surround your cubes dont collide, your cubes wont aswell. Next: If your relativ position to another cube changes sign in any coordinate after moving, you might have skipped an collision. If your sign doesnt change, you only have to check on each axis if your distance is smaller than half the side of both cubes together. If yes, you missed the collision point. I will probably add an answer with this and some interframe-collision tomorow, too tired now.